# ASP.NET CORE reading a simple text file with user selection offline mode

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, file, http-post, asp.net-core-mvc

I have made a MVC ASP.NET CORE 1.0 Webapp.
It will be used as offline app, i.e: server will be localhost always.
All I want to do is let the user click on a button called "browse" on the html page. and then a filepicker appears in front of them so they can just pick a file.
and then all I want to do is read that text file and do some logic with it later on.

**I have tried Following**

**HTML**

```
<form asp-action="Mark" asp-controller="Home" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="my-file-selector">
        <input id="my-file-selector" type="file" name="file" style="display:none;" onchange="$('#upload-file-info').html($(this).val());">
        Browse
    </label>
    <span class='label label-info' id="upload-file-info"></span>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

**Controller Code**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Mark(IFormFile file)
{

    return View();
}
```

**IMPORTANT :**

the above code works fine to upload the file, but I dont want to upload any file as it takes too much time and unnecessary memory space, I only want to read the contents of the text file which user selected.

**Thanks In Advance**

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using FileReader in JavaScript.

Here is an example:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function readFile(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  if (!file) {
    return;
  }
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contents = e.target.result; // here is your file content
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

document.getElementById('file-input').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);
```

That will take care of reading file content on the client site but if you need to do that in the back end (controller) then you've to upload the file.

Comment: is there a way in which user can only select the file and i can only send the absolute file path to the controller and then within controller i can read the file contents directly from the path specified?

Comment: That's not how you should do that. Either upload file or handle it on the client side (like I propose above). What is more, you can't select a file on a disc and send a path to the server because in 99% cases server (IIS) is on another machine.

Comment: It looks like you can use regular form submission (form tag with submit button), with ASP.NET MVC model binding, similar to the way it worked with ASP.NET MVC ("Classic" framework):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1